# Lighttpd: redirect any request to index.html

Tags: http, redirect, rewrite, lighttpd, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to send any request to the index.html with [lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite) in order to prevent 404 but I'm not smart enough because either the redirect matches itself or, for calls to subdirs, although the index.html gets served, it is not served from document root so all the paths are off and thus no images are shown.

```
$HTTP["host"] == "my.example.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/my/html/"
#       url.rewrite-once = ( "^/([^\./]+)/?([^\./]+)?(/|\.html)?$" => "/index.php?a=$1&b=$2" )
#       url.rewrite-once = ( "^.+?" => "/" )
#       url.redirect = ( ".*" => "http://my.example.com/index.html" ) # too many redirects
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few moments with Google suggests you want:

```
server.error-handler-404   = "/index.html"
```

---

> No, I don't want to handle the error. I want all requests to go to /index.html

You said you wanted to prevent a 404, this will do that. As the error is then handled it returns a 200 status code by default.

> And this also fails for my.example.com/some/thing.ext because the page is sent from /some/ so all paths are off.

No, it won't fail - it redirects all misses to `/index.html`.  That said, try:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.html" )
```

That will, once, rewrite any URL to `/index.html`.

Comment: No, I don't want to handle the error. I want all requests to go to /index.html

Comment: And this also fails for my.example.com/some/thing.ext because the page is sent from /some/ so all paths are off.